# android emulator adb devices offline or not found

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to install the android development environment on Fedora 13 (kernel 2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686.PAE). I installed ant 1.8 after removing ant 1.7.

I am getting the adb device either offline or not found for the emulator that I am running. Because of this, I am not able to install the application on the emulator.

I am following the instructions on http://www.aplusbi.com/?p=164 .

Kindly, help.
Thanking you,
Yours sincerely,
Shubham Jain